# TFS 2010 History comment edit

Tags: tfs

Is there anyway to edit coments in the history section after saving the work item? 
Nick

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you just mean check-in comments...

Double-click the Changeset you want to edit in the History list. Its details are shown in a dialog, and you can edit the check-in comment to your heart's content.

(Note that after making changes you have to manually refresh the history view before the new comment will be displayed in it)

Comment: I had just assumed it was the more complicated thing to change that he wanted to change but good point.

Comment: @NgM: kudos to you for being brave enough to poke the SQL databases directly ;-)